# Как добавить к секундам меньше 10 ведущий 0?

Tags: javascript

```js
let hourse = document.querySelector('.hours');
let minutes = document.querySelector('.minutes');
let secondes = document.querySelector('.secondes');

function time(hourse, minutes, secondes) {

  let data = new Date;
  let hous = data.getHours();
  let minuti = data.getMinutes();
  let second = data.getSeconds();

  if (second < 10) {
    let d = '0' + second;

    second.innerHTML = d
  }


  return hous + '.' + minuti + '.' + second;
}
let i = 0;

console.log(time());

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(time())
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div class="hours"></div>
<div class="minutes"></div>
<div class="seconds"></div>
```

1. Как добавить к секундам меньше 10 число 0 ?

Comment: И какая же ошибка? Секрет?

Comment: Какая ошибка?.,

Comment: `str.padStart(2, 0)` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: @StrangerintheQ тогда уж как-то так `str.toString().padStart(2, 0)` )

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych я специально написал str, у автора нет такой переменной, и назвал ее str чтобы было понятно что это строка

Comment: а ошибка в селекторе и имени переменной

Comment: ну чет как-то не факт что поможет ))))

Comment: @Stranger in the Q гений а где Ваше решение :((

Comment: @user345125 тут уже достаточно ответили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное определиться, у вас там Дом, Часы или Лошадь!) Если часто делаете такие опечатки, код можно писать в [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/6bjpna5k/), обернув всё в общую функцию `(function(){...})()` которая будет красить все объявленные переменные в синий цвет.

```js
let bubu = document.querySelector('.time-elem'); 
// Вместо трех элементов - один. Он будет указываться в качестве аргумента функции,
// чтобы в теории можно было в разных элементах показывать время.

function time(elem){
  let date = new Date;
  let hrs = date.getHours();
  let min = date.getMinutes();
  let sec = date.getSeconds();
  
  // Можно и без return... такая функция не обязательно должна что-то возвращать
  return elem.innerText = addZero(hrs) + ':' + addZero(min) + ':' + addZero(sec);
}

function addZero(num){ return (num < 10) ? "0" + num : num; } // см. "Тернарный оператор"

console.log( time(bubu) );

setInterval( () => {
  console.log( time(bubu) );
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="time-elem"></div>
```

А ваш вариант будет выглядеть так, если подправить:

```js
let hours = document.querySelector('.hours');
let minutes = document.querySelector('.minutes');
let seconds = document.querySelector('.seconds');

// При вызове функции - передаем все нужные значения в качестве аргументов:
console.log( time(hours, minutes, seconds) );

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(time(hours, minutes, seconds))
}, 1000)

function time(hours, minutes, seconds) {
/* Для удобства, названия этих параметров функции совпадают с объявленными выше 
  переменными, но они здесь не имеют к ним отношения. 
  Это внутренние переменные функции, которые будут принимать значение 
  в зависимости от аргументов функции в момент вызова */

  let data = new Date;
  let h = data.getHours();
  let m = data.getMinutes();
  let s = data.getSeconds();
  // innerHTML - писалось внутри условия. А надо было после.
  if (s < 10) { s = "0" + s; }
  if (m < 10) { m = "0" + m; }
  if (h < 10) { h = "0" + h; }

  hours.innerText = h; 
  minutes.innerText = m; 
  seconds.innerText = s; 

  return h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}

/* Все эти телодвижения с аргументами функции имеют смысл, только если хочется 
в будущем ставить такие таймеры в разные элементы. Иначе можно вообще убрать все
аргументы, и функция начнет работать просто при вызове time() но только
конкретно для этих элементов */
```

```css
div { display: inline-block; }

.hours::after, .minutes::after {
  content: ":";
}
```

```html
<div class="hours"></div
><div class="minutes"></div
><div class="seconds"></div>
```

Comment: в доме он тоже ошибку сделал, правильно `house`

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME  Почему // innerHTML - писалось внутри условия. А надо было после. ?

Comment: @user345125 Потому что числа же в любом случае надо было вставлять в innerHTML или innerText... а он работал только если число меньше 10 )

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так :

```js
const addLeadingZero = v => `00${v}`.substr(-2)

function time() {
  let date = new Date,
    hours = date.getHours(),
    minutes = date.getMinutes(),
    seconds = date.getSeconds();

  return [addLeadingZero(hours),
    addLeadingZero(minutes),
    addLeadingZero(seconds)
  ].join(':')
}

console.log(time());
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(time())
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

я так понимаю, что Вы добиваетесь результата, при котором секунды, имеющие значения от `0` до `9`, добавляли к себе `0` и имели вид `"00"`, `"01"`, `"02"` и т.д.
если да, то в строке:

```
if( second < 50 ){
```

замените `50` на `10`.
только учтите, что в консоли ожидаемого результат Вы всё равно не увидите, так как `second.innerHTML = d` работает только на элементах **DOM**.

Comment: Замена 50 на 10 ничего не меняет в отношении секунд меньше 10 в сравнении с кодом автора, стало быть вряд ли исправит неизвестную нам ошибку.